# Receiving entire data from socket before reading contents

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking

I'm currently trying to setup a server that accepts multiple clients and can receive and respond to messages.

The client and server use a common library at the core, which contains a `Request` class that gets serialized and sent from client to server and similar in reverse.

The server listens asyncronously to clients on each of their sockets and attempts to take the data received and deserialize the data into the `Request` class.

Data is sent via a `NetworkStream` using a `BinaryFormatter` to send directly on the socket. The received data is then parsed using a `Network Stream` on the other end.

I've tried using a `MemoryStream` to store the data to a buffer and then deserialize it as shown below, however this hasn't worked. Directly deserializing the `NetworkStream` didn't work either.

Searching around I haven't found much information that has worked for my use case.

This is the active code after the sockets are successfully connected:

On the request class, sending from the client:

```cs
public void SendData(Socket socket)
{
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream stream = new NetworkStream(socket, false);
        formatter.Serialize(stream, this);
        stream.Close();
}
```

Server Code receiving this data:

```cs
public void Receive(Socket socket)
{
    try
    {
        ReceiveState state = new ReceiveState(socket);
        state.Stream.BeginRead(state.Buffer, 0, ReceiveState.BUFFER_SIZE, new AsyncCallback(DataReceived), state);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.LogError(e.ToString());
    }
}

private void DataReceived(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    ReceiveState state = (ReceiveState)ar.AsyncState;
    int bytesRead = state.Stream.EndRead(ar);
    //Resolve Message
    try
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(state.Buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        Request request = (Request)formatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
        Logger.Log("Request Received Successfully");
        ResolveRequest(request, state.Socket);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.LogError(e.ToString());
    }
    //Resume listening
    Receive(state.Socket);
}

public class ReceiveState
{
    public byte[] Buffer;
    public const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
    public Socket Socket;
    public NetworkStream Stream;

    public ReceiveState(Socket socket)
    {
        Buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        Socket = socket;
        Stream = new NetworkStream(Socket, false);
    }
}
```

Currently, when `BeginRead()` is called on the `NetworkStream` I get a single byte of data, then the remaining data when the next `BeginRead()` is called.

e.g. The Serialized data should be: `00-01-00-00-00-FF-FF-FF-FF-01-...`

I receive: `00` followed by `01-00-00-00-FF-FF-FF-FF-01-...` which fails to deserialize.

I take it that the issue is that the `DataReceived()` method is called as soon as any data appears, which is the single byte taken, then the remainder arrives before listening is resumed.

Is there a way to make sure each message is received in full before deserializing? I'd like to be able to deserialize the object as soon as the last byte is received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP is a *stream* protocol, not a packet protocol. That means you are only guaranteed to get the same bytes in the same order (or a network failure); you are **not** guaranteed to get them in the same chunk configurations. So: you need to implement your own *framing* protocol. A frame is how you partition messages. For binary messages, a simple framing protocol might be "length = 4 bytes little-endian int32, followed by {length} bytes of payload", in which case the correct decode is to buffer until you have 4 bytes, decode the length, buffer {length} bytes, then decode the payload. **YOU NEED TO WRITE** the code that buffers the correct amounts, and at every point you need to deal with over-reading, back-buffers, etc. It is a complex topic. Frankly, a lot of the nuances are solved by using the "pipelines" API (I have a multi-part discussion on that API [here](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2018/07/pipe-dreams-part-1.html)).

However, additional guidance:

- **never ever** use `BinaryFormatter`, *especially* for scenarios like this; it **will** hurt you, and it is **not** a good fit for most use-cases (it also isn't a particularly good serializer); my recommendation would be something like protobuf (perhaps protobuf-net), but I'm arguably biased
- network code is subtle and complex, and RPC is largely a "solved" problem; consider trying tools like gRPC instead of rolling it yourself; [this can be very easy](https://protobuf-net.github.io/protobuf-net.Grpc/gettingstarted)